# Query executes in SSMS but crashes BIDS

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have the following query, which executes perfectly in SSMS. However, when I paste the code into a newly created dataset and click "execute", BIDS crashes and closes without notice - any suggestion as to the reason?

Code:

```
SELECT  MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectOwnerName,
        MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectUID,
        CurrentActivities.Activities_Current
FROM    MSP_EpmProject_UserView 
        Left Join
            (Select t1.projectUID, STUFF(
                (Select ', ' + t2.TaskName
                From (SELECT   MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectUID, MSP_EpmTask_UserView.TaskName
                    FROM MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView INNER JOIN MSP_EpmTask_UserView ON MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView.TaskUID = MSP_EpmTask_UserView.TaskUID INNER JOIN MSP_EpmProject_UserView on MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView.ProjectUID = MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectUID
                    WHERE (MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView.TimeByDay = @refDate) AND MSP_EpmProject_UserView.[Project Departments] = @prjDep) t2
                Where t1.ProjectUID = t2.ProjectUID
                Order by t2.TaskName
                For XML Path(''), Type).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,2,'') as Activities_Current
            From
                (SELECT   MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectUID, MSP_EpmTask_UserView.TaskName
                FROM MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView INNER JOIN MSP_EpmTask_UserView ON MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView.TaskUID = MSP_EpmTask_UserView.TaskUID INNER JOIN MSP_EpmProject_UserView on MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView.ProjectUID = MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectUID
                WHERE (MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView.TimeByDay = @refDate) AND MSP_EpmProject_UserView.[Project Departments] = @prjDep) t1
            Group by t1.ProjectUID) CurrentActivities On CurrentActivities.ProjectUID = MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectUID
WHERE   (MSP_EpmProject_UserView.[Project Departments] = @prjDep)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work my way around this by just pasting the code into the dataset, updating the fields, NOT clicking the "query designer" and by manually adding the parameters BIDS did not detect automatically (in my case an INT parameter for DATEADD() ). When I then close the dataset windows and use the dataset in my report, everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

I would try to create a view and see if that still crashes.  BIDS is not meant to be SSMS and it's interpretation of the XML parsing may be blowing it up.  You are translating values from a query using 'for xml', with 'type' which gets rid of the root element of the xml, then extending it, then nesting it, then nesting that, then left joining that, then you have a regular sql expression.  BIDS is not meant to do a lot of dynamic SQL, intense CLR, and xml node or xquery expressions nesting things in my experience.   Everytime I have thrown lot's of XML, table variables, recursive CTE's, dyanmic SQL... it blows up.  It's interpreter is blowing up I am guessing as it does not have the resources SSMS does to evaluate the expression and gives up in the form of a blow up.

My thought on doing the view is that the interpretation will be then forced on the SQL engine in the database to perform it's logic and execution plan and then return the results.  BIDS will just know it is a call to perform but not have to reason out the logic.  In my recollection SSRS with BIDS on 2008 has many issues with complex query logic and SSAS cubes.

This may not work but I know putting things to views, functions, or procs will often times fix issues with complex logic the engine has to perform.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I managed to work my way around this by just pasting the code into the dataset, NOT clicking the "query designer" and by manually adding the parameters BIDS did not detect automatically (in my case an INT parameter for DATEADD() )